# How to make your flexbox hover and flexible on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a website with a `flexbox` property. However I would like when a user hovers over the boxes, I would like the colour of the box to change and when on mobile, I would like the boxes to adjust accordingly.

Here is my code and my attempt:

HTML:

```
<div id="site-features" class="features-box">
 <a href="#"><h3>My heading 3 - one</h3> <img src="/assets/img1.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

 <a href="#"><h3>My heading 3 - two</h3> <img src="/assets/img2.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

 <a href="#"><h3>My heading 3 - three</h3> <img src="/assets/img3.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

 <a href="#"><h3>My heading 3 - four</h3> <img src="/assets/img4.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

<a href="#"><h3>My heading 3 - five</h3> <img src="/assets/img5.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.features-box {
    margin: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1560px;
    height: 380px;
    background-color: rgb(6, 67, 122);
    padding: 5px;
    /* this */
}

.features-box>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 5px rgb(255, 255, 255) solid;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.features-box>a:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

The problem is that when I hover, it only targets the text, not the box itself. How do I fix this to target the boxes and not the link as I would like the link to target the box and not just the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows -

```css
.features-box {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(6, 67, 122);
  padding: 5px;
  /* this */
}

.features-box>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 5px rgb(255, 255, 255) solid;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.features-box>a:hover {
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow ;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-features" class="features-box">
  <a href="#">
    <h3>My heading 3 - one</h3> <img src="/assets/img1.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

  <a href="#">
    <h3>My heading 3 - two</h3> <img src="/assets/img2.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

  <a href="#">
    <h3>My heading 3 - three</h3> <img src="/assets/img3.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

  <a href="#">
    <h3>My heading 3 - four</h3> <img src="/assets/img4.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>

  <a href="#">
    <h3>My heading 3 - five</h3> <img src="/assets/img5.png" height="95px" alt="read out"></a>
</div>
```

I have added `background-color:yellow` in the css which will help you change the background color of the cards and not only the text color. Also, I have removed the width of flexbox and made it wrap which helps to keep the layout flexible and it will adjust according to screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have a solution for the mobile and I will accept?

Comment: @JA-pythonista How do you want it to be on mobile? My solution adjusts according to screen size if you check

Comment: @JA-pythonista You can see it by running the code snippet that it has adjusted the layout. Click on full screen and you will get the result to be as your code had initially. As the screen size gets smaller, the cards will adjust accordingly in my code output

Comment: Yes, I saw it It looks good. The only problem is that I want it to like that when on PC and adjust when on mobile, With this it does not stay on the same row on PC :(

Comment: Do you have a remedy to this? I was thinking the media option

Comment: It won't stay row if the sum of card width exceed the screen width. Until your sum of card width is less, they will remain in the same row. You can decrease the width of cards to make the output stay on same row even on smaller screens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219211/discussion-between-ja-pythonista-and-abhishek).

Answer (score 0):

pythonista,

to change the box color, you need to set background. (color refers to the text).

```
.features-box>a:hover {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have solution for the mobile and I will accept?

Answer (score 0):

```
    color: green;
    background-color:
}
```

For mobile adjustment
You have specified a specific width to your class `.features-box`
So,for that you can specify

```
.features-box{
width:100%;
Flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```